# Program skips the second employee name user input

Tags: c

im a beginner. After the print of all the codes in the first employee (name,days,taxes etc.) I must try to provide a second employee info but my code doesn't take the user input in the second employee name, it skips and directly goes into the second employee days. the code just put a random character in the second employee name. I tried to rearrange my code but nothing happens.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int frstEmployeeDays;
    int thrdEmployeeDays;
    int frthEmploeyeDays;
    char firstEmployee[30];
    char thirdEmployee [30];
    char fourthEmployee [30];
    float sssPercentage, taxPercentage;
    int grossPay, netPay;
    const int salaryRate = 1500;
    const int pagibig = 200;
    float sss, tax;

    printf("Please enter your name:");
    scanf ("%[^\n]", firstEmployee);

    printf ("please enter the days you worked:");
    scanf("%d", &frstEmployeeDays);


    while (frstEmployeeDays >27)
    {
        printf("Error! Please Re-enter the day: ");
        scanf("%d", &frstEmployeeDays);
    }





    grossPay = salaryRate * frstEmployeeDays;


    if(grossPay < 20000){
        sssPercentage = 0.01;
        taxPercentage = 0.00;
    }

    else if (grossPay >20000 <30000 )
    {
        sssPercentage = 0.02;
        taxPercentage = 0.05;
    }

     else if (grossPay >30000 <40000)
    {
        sssPercentage = 0.02;
        taxPercentage = 0.05;
    }

    else {

        sssPercentage
         = 0.05;
        taxPercentage = 0.09;
    };



    sss = sssPercentage * grossPay;
    tax = taxPercentage * grossPay;


    netPay = grossPay - sss - tax - pagibig;

    printf("\nEmployees Name: %s", firstEmployee);
    printf("\t%d days\n", frstEmployeeDays);

    printf("\n\nYour gross pay is \t\t%d", grossPay);
    printf("\nSSS \t\t\t\t%f", sss);
    printf("\nTAX \t\t\t\t%f", tax);
    printf("\nPAG-IBIG \t\t\t%d", pagibig);
    printf("\nNETPAY \t\t\t\t%d\n\n\n", netPay);


        char secondEmployee[30];
        int scndEmployeeDays;


    printf("Please enter your name:");
    scanf ("%[^\n]", secondEmployee);

    printf ("\nplease enter the days you worked:");
    scanf("%d", &scndEmployeeDays);

    while (scndEmployeeDays >27)
    {
        printf("Error! Please Re-enter the day: ");
        scanf("%d", &scndEmployeeDays);
    }

    grossPay = salaryRate * scndEmployeeDays;

    printf("\nEmployees Name: %s", secondEmployee);
    printf("\t%d days\n", scndEmployeeDays);

    printf("\n\nYour gross pay is \t\t%d", grossPay);
    printf("\nSSS \t\t\t\t%f", sss);
    printf("\nTAX \t\t\t\t%f", tax);
    printf("\nPAG-IBIG \t\t\t%d", pagibig);
    printf("\nNETPAY \t\t\t\t%d\n\n\n", netPay);
    

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: OT: You really should read up on functions. Instead of repeating essentially the same code, write a function that can be called multiple times with different parameters. The read up on structures and array of structures to group employee info.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my question sir, greatly appreciated! if you don't mind, do you have link or videos for the lessons in that topics? i'm sorry im a beginner

Answer (score 2):

Your call to:

```
    scanf("%d", &frstEmployeeDays);
```

leaves the `'\n'` generated by the user pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> unread in `stdin`. Your next input:

```
    scanf ("%[^\n]", secondEmployee);
```

reads up until the `'\n'` (which is now the first character in `stdin`) effectively reading nothing into `secondEmployee` However, since you fail to ***check the return*** of `scanf()` that failure goes undetected resulting in undefined behavior.

Why? Because `"%c"`, `"%[..]"` and `"%n"` do not discard leading whitespace -- all other conversion specifiers do. How can you fix this?

```
    scanf (" %[^\n]", secondEmployee);
```

Include a `' '` (space) in the format string before the conversion specifier so that all leading whitespace is ignored.

How should you really fix it? Take all user input with `fgets()` using a sufficiently sized buffer (`1024` bytes recommended, or `128` bytes if programming on a microcontroller) and then parse needed values from the line of input using `sscanf()`. That way what remains in `stdin` and how it is treated does not depend on a `scanf()` conversion specifier and whether a *matching-failure* has occurred.

Comment: Thank you for your help sir david! Your help was greatly appreciated, I will apply that in my code sir!

Comment: You are very welcome. Of all input questions on this site, a full 90% of them are due to people attempting to use (well, misuse) `scanf()` for user input... Simply taking user input with `fgets()` eliminates virtually all the problems (and pitfalls) associated with input by `scanf()`. You just fill an array with `fgets()` and if you need to parse values from it, use `sscanf()` with the buffer. That way all input characters are consumed, so regardless whether a *matching failure* occurs with the conversion, your input stream is ready for your next user-input `:)`

Comment: Good luck with your coding! There is a lot to learn with C. Learning C is not a race, but more of a journey. So best advice I can give is to slow down and enjoy the journey.

Answer (score 1):

when the posted code is run through a compiler, the result is LOTS of warning messages.  The warning messages:

```
gcc -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11 -c "untitled1.c" -o "untitled1.o" 

untitled1.c: In function ‘main’:

untitled1.c:39:25: warning: conversion from ‘double’ to ‘float’ changes value from ‘1.0e-2’ to ‘9.99999978e-3f’ [-Wfloat-conversion]
   39 |         sssPercentage = 0.01;
      |                         ^~~~
      
untitled1.c:43:30: warning: comparison of constant ‘30000’ with boolean expression is always true [-Wbool-compare]
   43 |     else if (grossPay >20000 <30000 )
      |                              ^
      
untitled1.c:43:23: warning: comparisons like ‘X<=Y<=Z’ do not have their mathematical meaning [-Wparentheses]
   43 |     else if (grossPay >20000 <30000 )
      |              ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~

untitled1.c:45:25: warning: conversion from ‘double’ to ‘float’ changes value from ‘2.0e-2’ to ‘1.99999996e-2f’ [-Wfloat-conversion]
   45 |         sssPercentage = 0.02;
      |                         ^~~~

untitled1.c:46:25: warning: conversion from ‘double’ to ‘float’ changes value from ‘5.0000000000000003e-2’ to ‘5.00000007e-2f’ [-Wfloat-conversion]
   46 |         taxPercentage = 0.05;
      |                         ^~~~

      
untitled1.c:49:31: warning: comparison of constant ‘40000’ with boolean expression is always true [-Wbool-compare]
   49 |      else if (grossPay >30000 <40000)
      |                               ^
      
untitled1.c:49:24: warning: comparisons like ‘X<=Y<=Z’ do not have their mathematical meaning [-Wparentheses]
   49 |      else if (grossPay >30000 <40000)
      |               ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
      
untitled1.c:51:25: warning: conversion from ‘double’ to ‘float’ changes value from ‘2.0e-2’ to ‘1.99999996e-2f’ [-Wfloat-conversion]
   51 |         sssPercentage = 0.02;
      |                         ^~~~

untitled1.c:52:25: warning: conversion from ‘double’ to ‘float’ changes value from ‘5.0000000000000003e-2’ to ‘5.00000007e-2f’ [-Wfloat-conversion]
   52 |         taxPercentage = 0.05;
      |                         ^~~~
      
untitled1.c:58:12: warning: conversion from ‘double’ to ‘float’ changes value from ‘5.0000000000000003e-2’ to ‘5.00000007e-2f’ [-Wfloat-conversion]
   58 |          = 0.05;
      |            ^~~~
      
untitled1.c:59:25: warning: conversion from ‘double’ to ‘float’ changes value from ‘8.9999999999999997e-2’ to ‘9.00000036e-2f’ [-Wfloat-conversion]
   59 |         taxPercentage = 0.09;
      |                         ^~~~

untitled1.c:64:25: warning: conversion from ‘int’ to ‘float’ may change value [-Wconversion]
   64 |     sss = sssPercentage * grossPay;
      |                         ^

untitled1.c:65:25: warning: conversion from ‘int’ to ‘float’ may change value [-Wconversion]
   65 |     tax = taxPercentage * grossPay;
      |                         ^
      
untitled1.c:68:23: warning: conversion from ‘int’ to ‘float’ may change value [-Wconversion]
   68 |     netPay = grossPay - sss - tax - pagibig;
      |                       ^
      
untitled1.c:68:35: warning: conversion from ‘int’ to ‘float’ may change value [-Wconversion]
   68 |     netPay = grossPay - sss - tax - pagibig;
      |                                   ^
      
untitled1.c:68:14: warning: conversion from ‘float’ to ‘int’ may change value [-Wfloat-conversion]
   68 |     netPay = grossPay - sss - tax - pagibig;
      |              ^~~~~~~~
      
untitled1.c:11:10: warning: unused variable ‘fourthEmployee’ [-Wunused-variable]
   11 |     char fourthEmployee [30];
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      
untitled1.c:10:10: warning: unused variable ‘thirdEmployee’ [-Wunused-variable]
   10 |     char thirdEmployee [30];
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
      
untitled1.c:8:9: warning: unused variable ‘frthEmploeyeDays’ [-Wunused-variable]
    8 |     int frthEmploeyeDays;
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      
untitled1.c:7:9: warning: unused variable ‘thrdEmployeeDays’ [-Wunused-variable]
    7 |     int thrdEmployeeDays;
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      
Compilation finished successfully.
```

the statement:

```
*Compilation finished successfully.*
```

only means that the compiler used some 'workaround' for each of the problems, not that the desired code was produced.  ALL the problems need to be corrected.

A following are a couple of generalizations on fixes to help you:

regarding:

```
taxPercentage = 0.05;
```

This statement is trying to assign a 'double' into a 'float'.  This is because the literal `0.05` is a `double`.  To declare a float use:  `0.05f`  Note the trailing `f` in the literal

regarding:

```
else if (grossPay >30000 <40000)
```

This is not a valid syntax for a `if()` statement.  A proper/valid statement would be:

```
else if (grossPay >30000 && grossPay <40000)
```

regarding this kind of code sequence;

```
else if (grossPay >20000 <30000 )
{
    sssPercentage = 0.02;
    taxPercentage = 0.05;
}

 else if (grossPay >30000 <40000)
```

what happens when the `grossPay` is exactly `30000`?